# Deep belief networks: supervised or unsupervised?

Tags: deep-belief-networks

I want to know whether a Deep Belief Network (or DBN) is a supervised learning algorithm or an unsupervised learning algorithm?

After lot of research into DBN working I am confused at this very question. Some of the papers clearly mention DBN as **unsupervised** and uses supervised learning at at one of its phases -> fine tune. Some other sites clearly specifies DBN as **unsupervised** and uses labeled MNIST Datasets for illustrating examples.

There are some papers stress about the performance improvement when the training is unsupervised and fine tune is supervised. To top it all in a DBN code, at fine tune stage **labels** are used to find difference for weight updating.

So what I understand is DBN is a mixture of supervised and unsupervised learning. Why is it is then everywhere mentioned as **unsupervised**?

Answer (score 1):

Deep belief networks are generative models and can be used in either an unsupervised or a supervised setting.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_belief_network):

> When trained on a set of examples without supervision, a DBN can learn
>   to probabilistically reconstruct its inputs. The layers then act as
>   feature detectors. After this learning step, a DBN can be further
>   trained with supervision to perform classification.

If you have seen it mentioned as an unsupervised learning algorithm, I would assume that those applications stop after the first step mentioned in the quotation above and do not continue on to train it further under supervision. In that case it seems perfectly accurate to refer to it as an unsupervised method.

Comment: So an algorithm that is fully unsupervised and another one that contains supervised learning in one its phases both are apt to be termed as **unsupervised** ??

Comment: I'm just saying if you don't do the last phase, then it is unsupervised. It doesn't matter that it *can* then go on to be supervised, if you use it in an unsupervised way then what you have done is unsupervised learning. This is really just an argument over semantics, just think of this as two algorithms, the first is an unsupervised learning algorithm, the second is supervised and just happens to do everything the first algorithm does as its initial steps. The confusion is that they have the same name, and so to distinguish them people refer to the first as unsupervised.

Comment: Ok. So I wonder if DBN could be used for unlabelled dataset ?